# How to find the expected number of times required to empty the bag

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose we have  balls in a bag. Each time we pick a random positive integer  ≤  and remove  balls from the bag. 
The process is repeated until the bag becomes empty.

How can I find the expected number of times required to empty the bag.

Comment: After the first time, you have fewer than $n$ balls left.  Are you still choosing $k$ from $1$ to $n$, or from $1$ to the remaining number of balls?

Comment: I think from 1 to the remaining balls, since the initial constraint is given in that way.

Comment: OK, then I would recommend Noble Mushtak's answer below.  (Of course we assume that you are choosing $k$ according to the uniform distribution--so each integer from $1$ to the remaining number of balls is equally likely.)

Comment: @user3764893 Just so you know, I have updated my answer with a simplified formula for $f(n)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say the expected value of the number of times the bag is emptied when we start with $n$ balls is $f(n)$. First, let's get rid of the obvious base case: $f(0)=0$ times as the bag is already empty from the beginning.

If you pick $k$ balls, you have then picked from the bag once and you are expected to pick $f(n-k)$ since that's the number of balls left. Therefore, picking $k$ balls makes us expect to pick $1+f(n-k)$ times. We have $k=1$ to $n$ and each has a $\frac 1 n$ probability of happening, so we get:
$$f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n}(1+f(n-k))=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{f(n-k)}{n}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n}+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{f(n-k)}{n}=1+\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n f(n-k)}{n}$$
Now, let's try to relate this to $f(n-1)$:
$$f(n-1)=1+\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} f(n-1-k)}{n-1}=1+\frac{\sum_{k=2}^{n} f(n-k)}{n-1}$$
Now, if we subtract $1$ from both sides here, we can then multiply by $\frac{n-1}{n}$ to get the denominator of the fraction on the right-hand side to be $n$ like it is in the equation for $f(n)$:
$$\frac{n-1}{n}f(n-1)-\frac{n-1}{n}=\frac{\sum_{k=2}^{n} f(n-k)}{n}$$
Now, if we add by $\frac{f(n-1)}{n}$, we will get the sum to start at $k=1$ like it is in the equation for $f(n)$.
$$f(n-1)-\frac{n-1}{n}=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} f(n-k)}{n}$$
Now, add both sides by $1$ to get it exactly like the equation for $f(n)$:
$$f(n-1)+\frac 1 n=1+\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} f(n-k)}{n}=f(n)$$
Thus, we are simply adding $\frac 1 n$ from $f(n-1)$ to get to $f(n)$, so we get:
$$f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n}$$

Comment: For those of you who are interested, here is [$f(n)$ from $n=0$ to $n=100$](http://pastebin.com/raw/Vh1G0JAy).

Comment: A naive guess would be that you take out half the balls every time, so would expect something like $\log_2 n$ draws to be required.  Your model shows it is rather less than that.  It must be that the cases where you take out lots of balls pull it down more than cases where you don't take many out pull it up.  Good work.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thank you. I have simplified the formula for $f(n)$ above. Can please make sure my work is correct? Thank you!

Comment: Experimentally it is correct.  I didn't check the algebra, but it agrees to six places at $n=100$.  These are the [harmonic numbers H_n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) where $H_n \approx \log n + \gamma$ where $\gamma \approx 0.577$ is Euler's constant.