# What is the expected number of draws until a box of balls is empty? The only known information is the expected number of balls removed in each round.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Assume we start with a set $A$ consisting of $n \in \mathbb{N}$ elements.
We play a game consisting of multiple rounds, where in
each round, we remove a certain number of elements from $A$ until $A$ is empty.
The number of elements removed from $A$ is random and depends on how many elements are currently in $A$.

We can model this using $n$ different random variables,
$X_k: \Omega \longrightarrow \{1, \ldots, k\}$, where $k=1,\ldots,n$.
If we have $|A| = k$ in the current round, then the random variable $X_k$ models how many elements are removed in this round.

We do not know the distribution of $X_k$. What we do know is the expected value, $E(X_k) = \sqrt{k}$.

Now for the question: What is the expected number of rounds until $A$ is empty (as a function of $n$)? An upper bound alone for the expected number would also be helpful.

Similar questions have already been asked in
[How to find the expected number of times required to empty the bag](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2071608/how-to-find-the-expected-number-of-times-required-to-empty-the-bag?noredirect=1&lq=1)
and
[Distribution of number of drawings to empty the box of balls?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4088795/distribution-of-number-of-drawings-to-empty-the-box-of-balls), but I think my situation is a bit more general.

Comment: The fluid approximation assuming that the decrease in $\lvert A \rvert$ is always the square root gives that the set vanishes when $t = 2\sqrt{n}$. But I suspect the result isn't distribution-free.

Comment: For example, if we assume that with the $k$ elements in the set, we always drop to $0$ with probability $1/\sqrt{k}$ and stay at $k$ otherwise (ergo, an expected drop of $\sqrt{k}$), the time for the set to vanish is geometrically distributed with parameter $1/\sqrt{n}$, and that has a mean of $\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: You may be able to get some mileage out of doing a recurrence. Clearly $t_1 = 1$ since when there is only one ball left, you are forced to remove it with probability $1$. If you can express $t_k$ in terms of $t_j$ for $0 < j < k$, maybe you can get an expression that depends only on some moments of the distribution.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not getting anywhere with that. Already with two balls, using only the constraint that the expected number removed is $\sqrt{2}$, I get $t_2 = \frac{2p_{21}+2}{p_{21}+\sqrt{2}}$, with $p_{21}$ representing the probability of removing a single ball when there are two balls in the bag. This correctly produces $\sqrt{2}$ for the all-or-nothing distribution. But it looks unpromising for a general expression in terms of moments.

Comment: Possibly there's some two-dimensional generating function solution. I'll have to think about that.

Comment: @BrianTung Thank you for your ideas so far. I have two questions.
First: is $t_j$ defined as the expected number of moves in case that $A$ consists of $j$ elements?
Second:  what do you mean by "fluid approximation"?

Comment: And one more addition. An upper bound for the expected value as a function of $n$ would be enough for me.

Comment: 1. Yes, that's how I'm using $t_j$. 2. I mean where we assume that the number of elements is a real number, and that its trajectory can be modeled by a differential equation as $dx/dt = -\sqrt{x}$.